# Elegant way to convert numpy array to dictionary

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3-Dimensional numpy array with shape `(100,100,4)`. I want to generate a dictionary such that every value is a slice along the last axis. This would be the verbose approach:

```
dict = {
    'A01': arr[:, :, 0:1],
    'A02': arr[:, :, 1:2],
    'A03': arr[:, :, 2:3],
    'A04': arr[:, :, 3:4]
}
```

Now I have way more than 4 elements in the last axis and this verbose approach doesn't scale. Is there a way to generate the dictionary programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
d = {f'A{i + 1:02d}': arr[..., i:i + 1] for i in range(arr.shape[-1])}
```

(naming a variable with a reserved name e.g. `dict` is considered bad practice)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take on this:

```py
import numpy as np

my_array_1 = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
my_array_2 = np.array([[5,6], [7,8]])
my_array = np.stack([my_array_1, my_array_2])

d = dict(enumerate([x.squeeze() for x in np.split(my_array, my_array.shape[-1])]))

print(d)

#{0: array([[1, 2],
#        [3, 4]]),
# 1: array([[5, 6],
#        [7, 8]])}
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to OP's code. Aside from the `dict` key, the split array is not along the last axis. You should specify the `axis` parameter of `np.split()` too.